# get files names in a directory by neglecting first 3 letters of file name

Tags: python, text

I had to read all text files in a directory via python script, but first I had to remove the first 3 letters from every file to make index list.

the files names which contains data in a directory are are as follow.

```
zzz143
zzz146
zzz150
.
.
.
zzz250
```

I had to remove zzz from all files and make index list of all those files in a directory to read data from those files.
I know how to deal with files e.g

zzz.160.dat

for these kinds of files I use following code to remove the prefix and suffix.

```
def get_list(path, path_of_module_files ):
prefix, suffix = path_of_module_files.split("<index>")
d = {}
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for item in onlyfiles:
    if item.endswith(suffix) and item.startswith(prefix):
        text = item
        text = text[(find_str(text, prefix)+len(prefix)):]
        text = text[:find_str(text, suffix)]
        d[int(text)] = "/".join([path, item])
index_list = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
return index_list
```

this code deals with suffix and prefix, but now in my case they are a kind of prefix only.

and in my case now it is not split by . or -  and it is just zzz143. I had to get files names by removing zzz and list should be like this

```
143
146
150
.
.
. 
250
```

instead of

```
zzz143
zzz144
zzz145
.
.
. 
.
zzz250
```

If someone give me an idea or example how to do get all files names through looping to extract all files in that directory. i will really thankful

Comment: for splitting the suffix you could use os.path.splitext(). See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Comment: Are you saying you want only to extract numbers from filenames for indexing?

Comment: @IronFist yes I need to extract numbers from filenames for indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to extract numbers from filenames for indexing, then how matter the filename was, you can do it with:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '250.zzz'
>>> s1 = 'zzz123'
>>> s2 = 'abc.444.zzz' 
>>>
>>> re.search(r'\d+', s).group(0)
'250'
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'\d+', s1).group(0)
'123'
>>>
>>> re.search(r'\d+', s2).group(0)
'444
```

EDIT, this will work for all cases of filenames you mentioned:

```
def get_list(path, path_of_module_files):
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    d = {}
    for fil in onlyfiles:
        seq = re.search(r'\d+', fil) 
        if seq:       
            d[seq.group(0)] = os.path.abspath(fil)
```

EDIT2: You can also do it with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
>>> onlyfiles
['250.zzz', 'zzz123', 'abc.444.zzz']
>>> 
>>> list(map(lambda s: re.search(r'\d+', s).group(0), onlyfiles))
['250', '123', '444']
```

But again, if all you have is filenames with this format: 'zzz123.ext', then you don't need to overload your process with `re.search`, better use built-in method for faster process, like so:

```
>>> onlyfiles = ['zzz123', 'zzz456', 'zzz789']
>>> 
>>> list(map(lambda s: s[3:], onlyfiles))
['123', '456', '789']
>>> 
>>> list(map(lambda s: s.strip('zzz'), onlyfiles))
['123', '456', '789']
```

This method will automatically loop through all elements of you list with the need to explicitly writing a `for` loop.

EDIT3: using OrderedDict:

Either Simple `for` loop:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> index_dict = OrderedDict()
>>>  
>>> for fil in onlyfiles:
        k = int(fil.strip('zzz'))
        index_dict[k] = fil

>>> index_dict
OrderedDict([(123, 'zzz123'), (456, 'zzz456'), (789, 'zzz789')])
```

Or with `zip` and `map` as one liner expression:

```
>>> OrderedDict(zip(map(lambda s: int(s.strip('zzz')), onlyfiles), onlyfiles))
OrderedDict([(123, 'zzz123'), (456, 'zzz456'), (789, 'zzz789')])
```

Comment: but can you give me an example so that I can implement this for all files within a directory. mean I have 100 files with same prefix zzz143......zzz253. .......so that I can do automatically for all files in the directory. thanx alot for the help

Comment: I will apply this solution and will come back in a while. thanx alot for the reply

Comment: @ Iron Fist I am getting this .OrderedDict()
empty . Can you edit your solution to the above mention editing in my question. although my code deals with prefix and suffix, but I need to deal with prefix at the moment. thanx alot for your help.

Comment: For starter, check the content of `onlyfiles` list, if it empty (by for example `print(onlyfiles)` and see it there is any list, them that could be your issue,

Comment: thanx for the reply. I am trying to figure it out. just one little question. Can you edit your solution that if there are more than 10 files in the directory and it can loop to extract numbers from every file for indexing. thanx for the help. .

Comment: Yes, Just loop through your list of file and extract the numbers or you can use the `map` function, I'll update again my answer to you.

Comment: I apply your solution and it works fine. I had one little problem.  after using this  list(map(lambda s: s.strip('zzz'), onlyfiles)), and printing , it works and i get list like this .......['143', '144', '145',.... '250'] .......................but dictionary is empty and i get  this ...............OrderedDict()  ..............in above comment you mention that if onlyfiles consist of list, then it could be a problem. well I agree. is there solution to deal it. .............

Comment: because according to my code in question. after this line ..index_list = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))................I get index of all files along with their path. because I had to use it later in my code.  ...........if any tip, it would be great.

Comment: @ Iron Fist, if I got file numbers alongs with the path in OrderedDict , then it would be perfect. thanx alot for your precious time and help. .

Comment: thank you so much for your help and precious time. I accept your answer because it works perfectly according to my requirements. thanks a lot. you really save my day.

Comment: just for curiosity.  how to remove ' ' around file index like instead of OrderedDict([('123', 'zzz123'), ('456', 'zzz456'), ('789', 'zzz789')]).........................we get .OrderedDict([(123, 'zzz123'), (456, 'zzz456'), (789, 'zzz789')]).............like 123, 456 etc had no ' ' around them only in files names index , not zzz123.

Comment: @roy ..You will have to convert the string into integer using `int` method, I updated the answer

Comment: But Man seriously, you need to read and practice more with Python, you are asking very very basic stuff here, try to get more knowledge and practice, it makes things easier for you

Comment: I am really stupid. I know this stuff and practice before this conversion. but thanx a lot. I will take your advice and practice  more to understand better. thanx for the help and tip.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the first 3 characters of each item you can use list slicing like below:

```
my_list = ['zzz143', 'zzz146', 'zzz150']

new_list = [item[3:] for item in my_list]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> new_list
['143', '146', '150']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the prefix is `'zzz'` you could just replace it by `''`, like so :

```
def get_list(path, path_of_module_files):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, path_of_module_files)
    d = {}
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        suffix = device_name_format.split(".")[0].replace('zzz', '')
        d[suffix] = os.path.abspath(filepath)

index_list = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got empty dict . .like this   ...OrderedDict()
 . but after applying your solution I should get the all the files names . where I am doing wrong?.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use slice notation, if the three letters are different each time:

```
your_string = "ABC123"
your_string[3:]
>>> '123'
```

Or [string.lstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) if the prefix is the same every time.

```
your_string = "zzz123"
your_string.lstrip("zzz")
>>>> '123'
```